# Call MEL script from Python - Error occurred during execution of MEL script

Tags: python, file, maya, mel

I'm trying to create a simple Python script that will call a MEL script from within Maya to create a cube. Yay! Should be fairly straight-forward althougth I may have got the syntax for the source files wrong.

Here's what I have:

The runMEL.py Python file:
    import maya.mel as mel

```
def runMEL():
  print ("Running MEL from Python!")
  mel.eval('"source D:\Maya_Python\myMELScript.mel;"') # source of the file
  mel.eval("myMELScript;") #name of the function

runMEL() # call the function above
```

And the MEL script myMELScript.mel

```
global proc myMELScript()
// call a MEL script with Python
{
  polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 4 -ch 1;
  print("MEL just made a cube!");
}
```

I get the following from the console:

```
Running MEL from Python!
// Error: "source D:\Maya_Python\myMELScript.mel;"; // 
// Error: Line 1.40: Syntax error // 
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 5: Error occurred during execution of MEL script
Line 1.40: Syntax error #
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to due this through awkward mel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right, you have to pass the path as a string and escape it. Furthermore mel is picky with the forward `/` and backward `\` slashes, it expects `/`

## That should do:

```
mel.eval('source "D:/Maya_Python/myMELScript.mel"')
```

**Note**: Normally in python you could write your Path as well as

```
D:\\Maya_Python\\myMELScript.mel
```

but mel  is not clever enough so  it will escape the escape symbol :D

Comment: `mel.eval('source "D:/Maya_Python/myMELScript.mel"')` would be less messy

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, looks much better! And is more `pythonic` thanks for the contribution.  Next time please edit, i would have accepted it :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Just one last thing, Is the semicolon only needed on the second eval line?

Comment: How can I do this with relative paths in MEL? Thanks.

Comment: @GhoulFool If a MEL command is multiple lines, all but the last line need a semicolon. The last line is delimited by the end of file.